# Subset dataframe by every n column (R)

Tags: r, subset

I have a large df with ~400 columns.  Each set of 4 columns is related. I'd like to create a new dataframe for every 4 columns.

```
mydata <- data.frame("apple" = c("a", "b"), "pear"= c("c","d"), "orange"=c("e","f"), "grape"=c("g","h"), "fox" = c("i", "j"), "cat" = c("k","l"), "dog"=c("m","n"),"snake"=c("o","p"))

>mydata
    apple  pear  orange  grape  fox  cat  dog  snake
    a      c     e       g      i    k    m    o
    b      d     g       h      j    l    n    p
```

Desired output:

```
>new1
apple  pear  orange  grape  
a      c     e       g      
b      d     g       h 
   
>new2
fox  cat  dog  snake
i    k    m    o
j    l    n    p
```

I think this might be a job for dplyr and `group_by`, but not I'm not quite sure how to make `group_by` work with iterative numbers. Thoughts?

Alternatively, there might be a base approach using `subset.data.frame`, and creating vectors of "start" and "end" columns, ie:

```
n <- 1:400
start <- n[seq(1, length(n), 4)]
end <- start+3

new1 <- mydata[,c(start,end)]
```

with one of the `apply` functions thrown in to loop through it (but I'm still an R novice and not entirely comfortable with the `apply` suite yet)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way.  Say you have a dataframe `df` with 400 columns and you want a subset of dataframes each 4 columns wide.  Then create a vector that represents the first `df` column number of each subset dataframe.  Then use `lapply` to generate a list of the subset dataframes:

```
col1 <- seq(1, 397, 4)
listdfs <- lapply(col1, function(x) df[ , x:(x+3)])
```

Let me know if it works.

Test case:

```
m <- matrix(1:120, ncol = 12)
df <- as.data.frame(m)
col1 <- seq(1, 10, 3)
listdfs <- lapply(col1, function(x) df[ , x:(x+2)])
```

Comment: I'm trying to apply the unique function over each data frame in the list, and getting an error:  Error in listdfs[[x]] : invalid subscript type 'list' . Any advice?   
listdfs2 <- lapply(listdfs, function(x) unique(listsdfs[[x]]))

Comment: You want to apply unique to a `vector`, not an entire data frame.  E.g. `unique(mtcars)` returns `mtcars`, but `unique(mtcars$cyl)` returns a vector of 4, 6, 8.

Comment: Actually, going back to the original solution, I gave it a closer look, and it grapped the same 4 columns into each df in the list...

Comment: moxed, I see the error.  the col1:(col1+3) term should be replaced by x.  Fixed.  Apologize for the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gl` to create a grouping index for each 4 columns and use that in `split.default` to return a `list` of data.frames

```
lst1 <- split.default(mydata, as.integer(gl(ncol(mydata), 4, ncol(mydata))))
names(lst1) <- paste0("new", seq_along(lst1))
```

It is better to keep the datasets in a `list`.  If we need objects in the global env for each data.frame, use `list2env` after naming the `list`

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

-output

```
new1
#  apple pear orange grape
#1     a    c      e     g
#2     b    d      f     h

new2
#  fox cat dog snake
#1   i   k   m     o
#2   j   l   n     p
```

---

Also, if we want to use a `for` loop, create the sequence of index with `seq`, loop over the sequence of those index, and `assign` new objects into global environment while subsetting the data based on the index

```
start <- seq(1, ncol(mydata), by = 4)
for(i in seq_along(start)) {
     assign(paste0('new', i), mydata[start[i]:(min(start[i] + 3, ncol(mydata)))])
}
```